# How to expose a binary file in a .Net Restful Web Service?

Tags: .net, wcf, rest

Is it possible to expose a binary file over a .net (WCF) Rest Full web service.

I would like to have a binary file on my web server, which is available as a rest resource, like

.../api/firmware_2_0

to which my web service client could "get".

Is this possible, and who could I do it.

I am familiar with using Restful web service to provide JSON representation of data from a data base, but not binary files.

Comment: ??Why do you need WCF for this?  If it is a binary file, and you want to *GET* it, why not just let IIS serve it?

Comment: assuming the file or stream is being modifiend in-memory (i.e. you can't just let IIS handle it), you could use [streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx) with an http binding as a starting point.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that. But I already have the rest service in place for all the other interactions with the clients, and I'm just thinking about maintaining consistency.

Comment: I'm beginning the realise the stupidity of my question. This kind of thing can be handled much better by IIS, Or perhaps FTP. If Cheeso or silijon want to answer the question, I will give you a tick and or an upvote.

Comment: I have to comply with a goverment agency that wants ws to initiate the binary transfer. Sucks, but they will not accept other way

Answer (score 7):

Although I agree that in most cases IIS should be used for serving files, there are cases in which you actually want to expose raw binary over RESTful WCF Services.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-web.aspx,

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "?url={uri}")]
public Stream GetBinary(string uri)
{
    var binary = new byte[0]; // some sort of query
    var mimeType = ""; // some sort of query
    WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = mimeType;
    return new MemoryStream(binary);
}
```

Now realize, in doing this you are totally bypassing WCF's formatting.  As such, there will be no xml/json wrapping whatsoever.